# Adding two rows of a data frame together R

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I am trying to address a few troublesome rows in a dataframe in R. My recourse is to simply add them together, consoldiating two rows into 1. So for example if I had a 100 rows with X columns, I would have 99 rows with X columns after the operation. Ideally I would just pass two row numbers and they would be combined.  I would want to add each value for every column like a matrix operation almost. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide your data frame or a small sample of it using `dput`, and show us what the output would look like if solved correctly? That will help people here give you good solutions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the two rows together overwriting the second row and then remove the first row.

```
combine_rows <- function(data, row1, row2) {
  data[row2, ] <- data[row1, ] + data[row2, ]
  data[-row1, ]
}

# test using builtin data frame, BOD

BOD
##   Time demand
## 1    1    8.3
## 2    2   10.3
## 3    3   19.0
## 4    4   16.0
## 5    5   15.6
## 6    7   19.8

combine_rows(BOD, 2, 3)
##   Time demand
## 1    1    8.3
## 3    5   29.3   <-- this row is the sum of original rows 2 and 3
## 4    4   16.0
## 5    5   15.6
## 6    7   19.8
```